# NameError: name 'guild' is not defined. What the problem is?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

```
mC = guild.member_count
channel = client.get_channel(798156048571948463)
await channel.edit(name = f"Member count: {mC}")
```

The problem is in "mC" but why?

Comment: The variable `guild` on the first line is not defined. You cannot use a variable that you haven't set the value of. Where do you set it? Post your whole code, maybe you made a spelling mistake.

Comment: I haven`t set it yet. So how can i do that?

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_guild basically you need to find the guild's id and do `guild = client.get_guild(id)`, just like you did with `client.get_channel`

Comment: Ok thank you! Sorry for stupid question.

Comment: No problem, good luck with your bot. I would really recommend reading the official Python tutorial https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html before trying to write Python, it'll save you time in the long run.

Comment: also, I think you can hire people on Fiverr to write you a bot as well :)

Comment: I`d like to do that by myself because i like learning!-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first line, you are using `guild`, yet you have not defined it. To define `guild`, add above that:

```py
guild = client.get_guild(GUILD_ID)  # Change 'GUILD_ID' with your server id
```

Since you have defined `guild` now, you shouldn't get that error.

If you are trying to get the guild in which a message was sent, you should use the `ctx` object:

```py
guild = ctx.guild  # Only use if you're getting a message's guild
```

Comment: guild ID is an int, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what @IPSDSILVA did to get a specific guild or you can define `guild` by doing `ctx.guild.member_count` to get the member count of the server that the command was run in. Make sure you have `ctx` as a parameter if you do this way.